# Laravel 5.2, auth::check return true after login but false after redirect

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5, laravel-middleware

I'm trying to use the authentication system that comes built in with laravel 5.2. The login seems to be working correctly, if I replace the return statement with Auth::check(), it returns true. But when I redirect to '/', Auth::check() suddenly returns false in my Auth middleware.

Sessions Create method:

```
public function create(Request $request) 
{
    $email = $request->email;
    $password = $request->password;

    if(Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])) {
        return redirect()->intended('/'); // returns true when replaced with Auth::check();
    }

    return redirect("login");

}
```

Auth Middleware:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    if (Auth::guest()) {
        if ($request->ajax() || $request->wantsJson()) {
            return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
        } else {
            return var_dump(Auth::check()); // returns false
        }
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Routes file:

```
Route::post('/create-session', 'SessionController@create');
Route::get('/logout', 'SessionController@logout');
Route::get('/login', function() {
   return view('login');
});

Route::group(['middleware' => ['web', 'auth']], function(){
   Route::get('/', 'HomeController@getIndex');
});
```

Comment: Which session driver are you using?

Comment: File, but i have also tried with cookie

Comment: Are you using both web and auth middleware on these routes?

Comment: Please post your code from `routes.php`.

Comment: no, just the auth middleware

Comment: Please include the `web` middleware.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Ok, I placed the auth midlleware class into the web array in the kernel.php file. And used web middleware instead. But auth:check is still false and I got this error as well, "No supported encrypter found. The cipher and / or key length are invalid".

Comment: `php artisan key:generate` is what you'll need. And you should wrap everything in `Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function(){ //all your routes });` Otherwise your sessions and cookies will not apply to those routes.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I have updated my routes file with how it looks right now. But the auth is still false and i get redirected back to login page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ALL routes that require sessions (which Auth uses) must have the **'web'** middleware applied.

Also:

Your `Auth::check()` is being done in a code block that only runs if `Auth::guest()` is true.   `Auth::guest()` is the inverse of `Auth::check()`.

So you are saying in your middleware: If the current user is a guest (not authenticated), check if they are an authenticated user, which will always be false at this point.

Update:

Based on your comments: Do not add the authenticate middleware to the 'web' group. You will never be able to hit a 'web' route if you do this unless you were authenticated before you made this change. You are removing the ability to even be able to login if you do this.

Comment: It's fixed now, I had to apply the web middleware on all the login/logout routes and then use the auth middleware for the routes that require authentication.