# laravel auth middleware: one route, two views

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-5.3

I am building a store so i could learn laravel.
Like most stores, users can add items to a cart but cannot checkout until they register. 
How do i have the same route return a user name when authorized and a nothing when an authorized.
This seemed very easy to me at first:

```
@if(Auth::guest())
  Nothing || or login/register buttons
@else
  {{ Auth::user()->name }}
@endif
```

That works well when you have content that should only be visible to loyal users but for a store, you need users to see whats there to offer.

The problem is that, in my home controller, i need to add middleware auth in the constructor function so that `Route::get('/',HomeController@index);` returns a view and in the view use `@if(Auth::guest()) ...`, but adding this middleware means this route is not accessible if the user is not Authenticated and without it [you get this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35633942/laravel-5-2-authcheck-return-true-after-login-but-false-after-redirect).

So how do i have the same root route with Authenticated user data`(if authenticated)` without blocking the route from unauthenticated users?

Comment: Dont put `auth` middleware on any public route, use the `@if @else` block as mentioned in your question. Im not sure what you question is really, The issue in the question you linked is about a different middleware, `web`

Comment: I dont fully get what you mean? Auth::check()? will check to see if the user is authenticated?

Comment: @Birdy & @Steve , yes, but won't work if the route doesn't have auth middleware. If you are on ebay, go to ebay, the url is ebay.com, login the url is signin.ebay.com/... , after login the url is ebay.com and not ebay.com/home or ebay.com/authenticated-user.   The default laravel auth that comes with ```php artisan make:auth``` works if you have public data and auth only data. In this case, all data is public but a user may own an account to get more access e.g checkout

Comment: Without auth middleware, blade doesn't have data from Auth facade and with the middleware, those routes have restricted access

Comment: What you are trying to achieve will be very simple however i don't quite understand exactly what you mean, IT  sounds to mean like you are over complicating a simple solution and that is what is causing me to not quite understand what you mean so maybe someone else can help you out @Steve is more advanced than myself :) - To me it sounds like you already know the answer by using the if else statement because Auth is available in all views without.

Comment: Maybe updating the question with more detail or a screen shot will help?

Comment: @Birdy, i thought i knew the solution but it might not be working because i have not properly scaffolded the project or because there is is just a tiny mistake somewhere.

Comment: Ok let me ask this, Are you trying to display different data to Authenticated users than what gets displayed to guest users?

Comment: @Birdy the issue i've linked is also related to auth middleware, in the RedirectIfAuthenticated middleware, i set, redirect to the root ('/') but because i wan't the root accessible to the public, i've not added auth middleware. but then, if you access /login and login it redirects to '/' after login but Auth::check will be false, always. Add the middleware and the root redirects to '/login' which is what i don't want

Comment: @Birdy, same data

Comment: In a controller, ```return view('home',['user' => Auth::user()? Auth::user() : 'blank']``` woun't work either. Will always be 'blank' without the middleware

Answer (score 0):

If i am understanding what you are asking (Though i believe i dont quite fully get what you mean).

You want to use the Auth::user() or Auth::check() throughout your views? This should be available out of the box especially when you have used php artisan make:auth.

One way to achieve this would be to use view->share() in a service provider on the boot method, This will then make the $user variable or $isSignedIn variable available in all views.

For example in your App\Providers\AppServiceProvider

```
namespace App\Providers;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        view()->share('isSignedIn', Auth::check());
        view()->share('user', Auth::user() ?: new User());
    }

    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

If this is not going to help let me know and i can help towards getting the outcome you need.

**- Update**

On your HomeController can you try:

```
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
```

and in your index() method can you add:

```
if(Auth::user()){
$user = Auth::user();
}else{
$user = new User();
// or you can use:
$user = Auth::guest();

// If you use $user = Auth::guest() you can remove the Use App\User;

}

return view('home', compact('user'));
```

See if that does anything for you?

Comment: user remains undefined

Comment: Can you take a screen shot of the issue so i can see exactly what it is your trying to achieve, From what i believe.. You want to use authenticated facades in views but without your route being in the Auth only routes?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9wXL.png

  https://i.stack.imgur.com/KbPWc.png

  https://i.stack.imgur.com/4cnjK.png

  https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUxKe.png @Birdy

Comment: Bottom line is, Auth facades not returning anything in blade or controller unless there is Auth middleware on a route, Route not accesible for unauthenticated users where auth middleware exists. How to have both on one route with one view is my question. Hope my question is clear now

Comment: Failing that screen shot your routes please.