# Laravel 5.7 auth can't get success

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, oauth

I tried to make auth API, I am success registed.
Than Signin can't success.
Please help me ,thanks.

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    try
    {
        if (!$request->has('Account') 
        || !$request->has('Password'))
        {
         throw new Exception('Parameter missing');
        }

         $checkUser = DB::table('Users')->where('Account',$request->Account)->first();
        if(empty($checkUser))
        {
            throw new Exception('No Data');
        }
        $data = ([
            'Account' => $request->Account,
            'Password' => $request->Password,
        ]);  

        if(!Auth::attempt($data))
        throw new Exception('Verification error');
```

this db info.

[image]

Comment: show your code of  registration .

Comment: $check = DB::table('Users')->where('Account',$request->Account)->first();
            if(!empty($check->UserID))
            {
                throw new Exception('Data duplicate or exist');
            }
            $user = new User([
                'Account' => $request->Account,
                'Password' => bcrypt($request->Password),
                'ConfirmPassword' => $request->ConfirmPassword,
                'CreateDateTime'=>date('Y-m-d'),
                'UpdatedDateTime'=>date('Y-m-d')
            ]);
            $user->save();

Comment: did you bcrypt the logged in password like this `'Password' => bcrypt($request->Password),`?

Comment: It's wrong . Every time ( bcrypt ) was different.

Comment: check here. for your peace in coding :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35633942/laravel-5-2-authcheck-return-true-after-login-but-false-after-redirect

Comment: Dd you override username ? By default Laravel use `email` field for authentication.

Answer (score 1):

Try following for register need to hash password before save in database:

```
User::create([
    'Account' => $request->Account,
    'CreateDateTime' => date('Y-m-d'),
    'UpdatedDateTime' => date('Y-m-d'),
    'Password' => Hash::make($request->Password),
]);
```

Comment: I using to  'Password' => Hash::make($request->Password), but i got error. I had using Hash.

Comment: Add `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;` in top

Answer (score 0):

try this way it might helpful and evn ry validator also:
       and if not sure about pass word then first debug

```
   $table->string('password', 60)->nullable();
    ----------------------------------------------------
   return Validator::make($data, [
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required',
    ]);
    -----------------------------------------------
   $user_data=User::where('username','=',$request->username)->first();
   $userScope=$user_data->scope;

   Input::merge([
        'client_id' => env('CLIENT_ID'),
        'client_secret' => env('CLIENT_SECRET'),
        'scope' => 'admin'
    ]);

    $credentials = $request->only(['grant_type', 'username', 'password','scope']);


    $validationRules = $this->getLoginValidationRules();

    $credentials["client_id"] = env('CLIENT_ID');
    $credentials["client_secret"] = env('CLIENT_SECRET');


    $this->validateOrFail($credentials, $validationRules);

    try {
        if (!$accessToken = Authorizer::issueAccessToken()) {
            return $this->response->errorUnauthorized();
        }
    } catch (\League\OAuth2\Server\Exception\OAuthException $e) {
        throw $e;
        return $this->response->error('could_not_create_token', 500);
    }

    $accessToken["groups"][] = $userScope;

    return response()->json(compact('accessToken'));
```